# filtering an array of timestamps

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm working on a project that requires me to sort information by timestamp. All the information comes from a CSV file from a url. My plan is to 1)create an 1st array containing complete data
2)create a new Array of mapped timestamps
3)remove the duplicate timestamps
4)search the 1st Array using the new mapped and reduced Array.

The issue I think I'm having is that the Array contains the header "timestamp" at irregular intervals which I'm unable to filer out. This is what I'm doing.

1. I am creating an array from a CSV file

```
const data = await csv({ delimiter: [";"] }).fromStream(request.get(fileUrl));
```

2)The data that I get has timestamps which I am then mapping

```
const timeStamps = data.map(ts => ts.timestamp)
```

the next step would be to remove the duplicate timestamps

[image]

```
function removeDuplicate(array, key) {
     var check = new Set();
     return array.filter(obj => !check.has(obj[key]) && check.add(obj[key]));
```

However when I try to run the above function it only returns the first timestamp. My thinking is that its running into the string 'timestamp and then stoping for some reason so I'm trying to filter out 'timestamp' from the array using

```
const filterdTimestamps = timeStamps.filter((ts) => ts.timestamp === 'timestamp');
```

Haven't been able to figure out what I'm doing wrong yet so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `obj[key]` should be `obj`, as in `timeStamps` every single item is a string, and has no custom keys (your actual objects were gone at the `data.map(ts => ts.timestamp)` step). Right now you have a single item only, because `"somestring"[key]` is `undefined`, and after you put an `undefined` into the `Set`, the further `undefined`s you get will be already there, so they're duplicates.

Comment: Thanks that bit of information solved the rest of my issues.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to filter it. Create a set using the array, then spread it into a new array.

```js
const input = ['5', '5', '5', '6', '6', '6', '7', '7','7','timestamp']
const output = [...new Set(input)]
console.log(output)
```